# Adding dummy copy constructor to std::packaged_task

Tags: c++, c++11, packaged-task

I'm trying to bypass std::packaged_task's lack of a copy constructor so that I can pass it into a std::function (which will only ever be moved).

I inherited from std::packaged_task and added a dummy copy constructor, which I assume shouldn't be called if I never copy the std::function it's moved into.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
class MyPackagedTask : public std::packaged_task<T()> {
  public:
    template <typename F>
    explicit MyPackagedTask(F&& f)
      : std::packaged_task<T()>(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

    MyPackagedTask(MyPackagedTask&& other)
      : std::packaged_task<T()>(std::move(other)) {}

    MyPackagedTask(const MyPackagedTask& other) {
      // Adding this borks the compile
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyPackagedTask<int> task([]() {return 0;});
    auto future = task.get_future();
    std::thread t(std::move(task));
    t.join();

    std::cout << future.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this with gcc 6.2.1 I get the following error message (just the end part, let me know if you want the whole thing...):

```
/usr/include/c++/6.2.1/future:1325:6: error: invalid use of void expression
      (*_M_result)->_M_set((*_M_fn)());
```

The error message was unparseable to me, so I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if the compiler is failing.

Comment: Why in the name of Bjarne Stroustrup are you inheriting from `std::packaged_task`? Shouldn't you at best compose it? `std::packaged_task` is a resource that promises to produce something, You may want to see [Yakk's work](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2872/type-erasure/18042/a-move-only-stdfunction)

Comment: As stated in the question, I want to circumvent the requirement for a copy constructor in std::function. Composing makes me have to provide wrappers for all the functionality in `std::packaged_task` and doesn't get rid of the bug I'm encountering.

Comment: As to why: I have a thread queue that you can post tasks to in the form of a std::function<void()>.

I want to post non-void functions by wrapping them in a packaged_task, plop that on the queue and use the future from the packaged_task to get the result.

Comment: Why are you creating a thread for a package_task? They run asynchronously by default.

Comment: Are you thinking about std::async? packaged_task doesn't run asynchronously unless you do so manually.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Thanks for the link. I've seen solutions based on creating a move only version of std::function but I'd rather not have to roll my own version of std::function unless I really have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The move constructor definition is not correct, it forwards `std::packaged_task<T()>&&` as `MyPackagedTask&&` and that invokes a wrong constructor of `std::packaged_task<T()>`. This is the cause of the compiler error you observe.

The correct one:

```
MyPackagedTask(MyPackagedTask&& other)
  : std::packaged_task<T()>(static_cast<std::packaged_task<T()>&&>(other))
{}
```

In there `static_cast<std::packaged_task<T()>&&>(other)` does both the upcast to the base class and `std::move`.

Comment: Could you just write `std::move<std::packaged_task<T()>>(other)` for more type-safety?  (That wouldn't allow a down-cast, but only upcast).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

That will result in the exact same thing:
`static_cast<std::packaged_task<T()>&&>(other)`

Comment: @SpencerMcLaughlin `std::move<T>` fixes the formal parameter to be of type `T`, so that upcast happens implicitly.

Comment: Ah I see now.

@TobySpeight Sorry, I derped there.